# how to get the lat and lon coordinates in method viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Good day, I created two empty variables lat, lon, then the method forwardGeocoding gave them the coordinates, how to get the lat and lon coordinates in method viewDidLoad? Thank you.https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLvqv.png

Comment: you can get lat long from object of cllocation manager.

Comment: remove all code form function and write  in to viewdidload method..OR Another Method you can assign your block in one variable and access that..in viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

Here it is your solution.

You can use multiple return statements on swift. Here is viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let (latL, lngL) = self.forwardGeocoding("address")
        self.lat = latL
        self.lng = lngL
        print("\n viewDidLoad lat = \(lat) lng = \(lng)")
    }
```

And below is the forwardGeocoding function demo how to return lat lng.

```
func forwardGeocoding(address:String) -> (CLLocationDegrees, CLLocationDegrees){

        //--------------------- Demo Code -----------------
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        let location = locationManager.location
        let coordinate = (location?.coordinate)!
        //-------------------------------------------------

        //Pass your lat long as below back to viewDidLoad
        return (coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately both versions are not suitable